# TYPO3 extension input form cannot save object

Tags: forms, parameters, typo3, extbase

I am currently developing an extension where I want to create a new object (`request`) which contains a reference (UID) to a second object (`bike`). Simply put, I want to submit a contact form that references the corresponding product.

It is already possible to create a request object in the backend.

But when I try to submit the frontend contact form, I get the following error:

```
#1298012500: Required argument "bike" is not set.
```

Here an excerpt from the input form (*New.html*):

```
<f:form id="request" class="Tx-Formhandler col col-2" action="create" name="newRequest" object="{newRequest}">

            <div class="content">

                <f:form.hidden property="bike" value="{bike.uid}"/>

                <div class="row"> 
                    <div class="col c3">
                        <label for="salutation"><f:translate key="tx_chiliusedbikes_domain_model_request.salutation" />:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input col c9">
                        <f:form.select property="salutation" options="{Herr: 'Herr', Frau: 'Frau'}" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row required">
                    <div class="col c3">
                        <label for="firstname"><f:translate key="tx_chiliusedbikes_domain_model_request.firstname" />: *</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input col c9">
                        <f:form.textfield property="firstname" class="required" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The UID of the bike is correctly passed into the form. But still, the error states that the property is not set. What could be the reason?

Comment: Try to `<f:debug>{newRequest}</f:debug>` to check if whole object is bound properly

Comment: I'm not quite sure where I should write such a debug statement - the error occurs when I submit the form in the New template. And when I write the debug statement directly into the New template, the object is yet waiting to be filled (NULL), of course...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemingly, the problem was caused by the missing attribute `controller` of the form. Now it works flawlessly:

```
<f:form id="request" class="Tx-Formhandler col col-2" action="create" name="newRequest" object="{newRequest}" controller="Request">
```